# Python 2.7 subprocess Popen returns None

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, pytest, popen

I am currently working on a set of integration tests with pytest in python 2.7 that do the following:

1) run a server binary in the background on my local machine

2) send requests to the server and validate the results

3) terminate the background server process

Everything seems to be working fine, except that I am unable to terminate the server process running on my computer.  Although it continues to run on my computer, Python seems to have forgotten about it; my `Popen` object is `None`.

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'terminate'`

Are there any thoughts on what is causing this?  Am I missing something obvious?

```
import time
import subprocess

server_background_process_pipe = None

def setup_module():
    # Start the test server in the background
    cmd = 'bin/my_server --key1='+value1+' --key2='+value2+' &' # The '&' tells my bin to run in the background
    server_background_process_pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print(server_background_process_pipe) # prints '<subprocess.Popen object at 0x10aabd250>'
    time.sleep(1) # Wait for the server to be ready

def test_basic_get_request():
    print(server_background_process_pipe) # prints 'None'
    response = send_request_to_server() 
    fail_if_not_as_expected(response) # Response is exactly as expected

def teardown_module():
    # kill the server that was launched in setup_module to serve requests in the tests
    # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'terminate'
    server_background_process_pipe.terminate()
```

Extra info:

It is `None` even while the server process is still running.  It is `None` while the tests are running.  It runs long after the test suite finishes. If I re-run the tests, I get a message in my console that my server failed to deploy because it is already running.  The tests still pass because they send requests to the server from the previous execution.

Since the server needs to run in the background, I am using the subprocess.Popen constructor directly instead of one of the convenience methods like `check_output`.

Comment: You only ever assign `None` to the module global variable `server_background_process_pipe`. You could use a `global` statement in your function that assign to `server_background_process_pipe` but it is best to avoid global mutable state to begin with.

Comment: Add `global server_background_process_pipe` to the top of `def setup_module():`

Comment: Or, better, add `return server_background_process_pipe` to the end, and have the caller do `server_background_process_pipe = setup_module()` (and, ideally, pass it in to the other methods).

Comment: Or, if this is meant to act like an object that holds onto some state that persists between calls, define a `class` and store it as `self.server_background_process_pipe`.

Comment: Man, that's embarrassing!  Thanks for all of the feedback!  I like your last idea the best, abarnet, I think I might go with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
def setup_module():
    …
    server_background_process_pipe = subprocess.Popen(…)
```

`server_background_process_pipe` is a local variable. It's never assigned to global `server_background_process_pipe` so global `server_background_process_pipe` is always `None` and the code

```
def teardown_module():
    server_background_process_pipe.terminate()
```

tries to get attribute `terminate` from None.

What you want is to make the initial assignment to the global variable:

```
def setup_module():
    …
    global server_background_process_pipe
    server_background_process_pipe = subprocess.Popen(…)
```